Docker Apache Kafka 3.7.0: Cannot modify the advertised.listeners
I'm very a Kafka beginner. I tried to make a very simple example with the Apache Kafka docker version 3.7.0 and kafka-python. On the same machine, my python code (simple code as in here) works fine with the kafka-console tools inside the docker. However, with the same code, it is not work with a remote machine (one machine run docker kafka, and another run the python code kafka-python). I tried to change the advertised.listeners config (from localhost to the external address of the server) in the server.properties, but when I restart the docker, this is still (advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092). I also tried to stop and start the kafka-server without restart the docker with kafka-server-stop.sh and kafka-server-start.sh but the first said that "No kafka server to stop".
Please give me some suggestions? Thank you in advanced.
Edit : Detail of my steps:
1- I follow the steps in QuickStart:

$ docker pull apache/kafka:3.7.0
$ docker run -d --net=host --name kafka apache/kafka:3.7.0

2- I enter the kafka container

$ docker exec -it kafka /bin/bash

then modify the file at /opt/kakfa/config/server.properties

Please show your docker run command or compose file, and how you're modifying properties. Are you following any examples? https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/docker/examples/jvm/single-node/plaintext/docker-compose.yml

@OneCricketeer Thank you for considering my question. I have added the detail in the post. In fact, I have not tried the docker-compose yet but followed the Apache QuickStart https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart. I will check the docker-compose and update the result to you.

You can't modify the broker properties while the container is running. You should mount the file to override, or use environment variables. The default setup does not allow connections from external machines
